# Do higgs field affect rest mass and relativistic mass?

Tags: mass, higgs

I know most of the "mass" comes from the binding energy such as gluon but suppose I apply a force on a matter particle, do I change the interaction between the particle and the higgs field? How does it work?

Comment: @Qmechanic: I looked up Yukawa interaction for hours but still not quite get it, can you show me how the other answer helps explain higgs mechanism, the result I got are meson and binding nuclear forces.

Comment: For starters, consider to remove the obsolete notion of relativistic mass. This only obfuscates the real question here.

Comment: @Qmechanic: I found spontaneous symmetry breaking and fields can interact with each others, I hope I'm on the right track thank you.